# How to add two values from range slider to form a single value

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some code that adds two values together to form a complete one. What I'm trying to get is the values from Bedrooms and Bathrooms to add to a single value. Each value is a numeric value, but I don't know how to combine them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the JS Fiddle. I'm not sure why it's not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/n48kvejy/22/

```
var basePrice = 85.00;

function sliderChange(val) {
  document.getElementById('bed_display').innerHTML = val;
}

function sliderChange2(val) {
  document.getElementById('bath_display').innerHTML = val;
}

function changePrice(val) {
  if (val == 1) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice;
  }
  if (val == 2) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 10;
  }
  if (val == 3) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 35;
  }
  if (val == 4) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 70;
  }
  if (val == 5) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 95;
  }
  if (val == 6) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 120;
  }
}

function changePrice2(val) {

  if (val == 1) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice;
  }
  if (val == 2) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 25;
  }
  if (val == 3) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 50;
  }
  if (val == 4) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 75;
  }
  if (val == 5) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 100;
  }
  if (val == 6) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = basePrice + 125;
  }
}
```

I would like the code to do something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/uL23spL1/1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better you bind your events in the script instead of binding it inline.

- Use `+` operator to add the values

One rudimentary way of doing this is

```js
var basePrice = 85.00;
var bedroomCostFactor = [0, 10, 35, 70, 95, 120];
var bathroomCostFactor = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125];

document.querySelector('#bed_service').addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
 var value = evt.target.value;
  // value will be a string. Coercing to a number using +value
  var bedCost = parseInt(getBedroomCost(+value), 10).toFixed(2);
  
  document.querySelector('#bed_display').innerHTML = value;
  document.querySelector('#bed_cost').innerHTML = bedCost;
  
  getTotalCost();
});


document.querySelector('#bath_service').addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
 var value = evt.target.value;
  // value will be a string. Coercing to a number using +value
  var bathCost = parseInt(getBathroomCost(+value), 10).toFixed(2);
  
  document.querySelector('#bath_display').innerHTML = value;
  document.querySelector('#bath_cost').innerHTML = bathCost;
  
  getTotalCost();
})

function getTotalCost() {
 var bedCost = parseInt(document.querySelector('#bed_cost').innerHTML || 0, 10);
  var bathCost = parseInt(document.querySelector('#bath_cost').innerHTML || 0, 10);
  
  document.querySelector('#price').innerHTML = (bathCost + bedCost).toFixed(2);
}


function getBedroomCost(val) {
 return basePrice + bedroomCostFactor[val - 1];
}

function getBathroomCost(val) {
 return basePrice + bathroomCostFactor[val - 1];
}
```

```html
<div class="form__fields">
  <div class="form_text_fields">
    <span class="form_label">Bedrooms: </span><span class="choice_display" id="bed_display">1</span> </div>
    <div class="form_text_fields">
    <span class="form_label">Cost: </span><span class="choice_display" id="bed_cost">0</span> </div>
  <div class="form_input_field">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="bed_service">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form__fields">
  <div class="form_text_fields">
    <span class="form_label">Bathrooms: </span><span class="choice_display" id="bath_display">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form_text_fields">
    <span class="form_label">Cost: </span><span class="choice_display" id="bath_cost">0</span> </div>
  <div class="form_input_field">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="bath_service">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="price">

</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I would have never figured that out on my own, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Sushanth, I have an issue with the code. When I drag both items back to 1, 1, that's where I want the base price to be at which is supposed to be 85, but it shows the total for each which totals to 170.

Comment: I'm going to try to work with it, but I have an example of something I would like it to perform like here: https://jsfiddle.net/n48kvejy/70/. If you could help me out, it would be of tremendous help. Thank you!

Comment: I did it :) Thanks you.

Comment: @hd326 Glad you figured it out :)